# I am getting an error when trying to export my keras model to tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

```
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
export_path=r'tensorflowservingmodel'
export_version=1
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
signature = predict_signature_def(
    inputs={'input': new_model.inputs[0]},
    outputs={'output': new_model.outputs[0]})


with K.get_session() as sess:

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess=sess,
        tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
        clear_devices = True,
        signature_def_map={
            signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature}
    )
builder.save()
print("tensorflow serving.......")
```

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call 
>   last)  in 
>        2 export_path=r'tensorflowservingmodel'
>        3 export_version=1    ----> 4 builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
>        5 signature = predict_signature_def(
>        6     inputs={'input': new_model.inputs[0]},
>          ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py
>   in **init**(self, export_dir)
>       93       raise AssertionError(
>       94           "Export directory already exists. Please specify a different export "    ---> 95           "directory: %s" % export_dir)
>       96 
>       97     file_io.recursive_create_dir(self._export_dir)
>          AssertionError: Export directory already exists. Please specify a    different export directory: tensorflowservingmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this directory 'tensorflowservingmodel', make sure it does not exist before exporting the model.

```
rm -r tensorflowservingmodel
```

Comment: sorry the command you wrote above should l paste it in commandline or whats?

Comment: It's the command you need to use to delete the directory from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem l had already created a file called tensorflowservingmodel, that's why the program was saying directory already exist.l had to delete the file directory and re rerun the code.